# Array of objects - return objects by order & return average ranking

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

This is a practice hw question.

**INSTRUCTIONS**

You have an array of objects in JavaScript. Each one contains a name (a string) and ranking (a number).

Write two functions, one to return the objects ordered by ranking and another to return the average ranking.

I have it sorted, but need to find the average ranking as well.

**CODE**

```js
let obj = [{name: "bob", ranking: 2}, {name: "rob", ranking: 3}, {name: "cob", ranking: 1}];

const output = obj
    .sort((a, b) => a - b);

function avgRanking(num) {
  let sum = obj.reduce((previous, current) => current += previous);
  let avg = sum / obj.ranking.length;
  return avg
}

console.log(output); 
console.log(avgRanking()); // NaN
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why would you get only the rankings and not the whole objects?

Comment: You say you want to have a function that returns the objects ordered by ranking, your function does exactly that. So you are not asking ask how to fix it, you just ask for clarification right?

Comment: There is not a single question (mark) in your post. It sounds more like an exercise given by teachers or in interviews.

Comment: you are correct, edited to reflect that

Answer (score 2):

`.sort()` sorts an array, and *only* that. If you start with an array of objects and call `.sort()` on it, the array will still be an array of objects, only (possibly) in a different order.

If you want a sorted array of just the rankings, you need to `.map` to extract the values (either before or after sorting). You should also probably use a better variable name for the array - it's an array, not a plain object, so perhaps name it `arr` or `users` (or something that more accurately describes what the collection is), else there's a good chance of confusion:

```js
const users = [{name: "bob", ranking: 2}, {name: "rob", ranking: 3}, {name: "cob", ranking: 1}];

const output = users
  .map(obj => obj.ranking)
  .sort((a, b) => a - b);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: ... or even better `users` or `players` or whatever makes sense